# Sed Replace With Two Different Variable Values

Tags: bash, variables, replace, sed, sh

I want to replace old path variable to new one like this:

```
script_path=$(readlink -f "$0") #[/home/username/Desktop/script]
desktopfolder_old=/home/username/Desktop
desktopfolder_new=/home/username/NewOne
script_path_new=$(echo "$script_path" | sed -e "s/$desktopfolder_old/$desktopfolder_new/")
```

Because the bash script will be moved while it is running.
But couldn't do it. What would it be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `/`s in the variables are going to totally mess up the `sed "s/$var...` after the var substitutions. The `-e` is also superfluous. Try instead:

```
script_path_new=$(echo "$script_path" | sed "s|$desktopfolder_old|$desktopfolder_new|")
```